# Determining order of the group for an elliptic curve defined over a finite field

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

I need to find out the order of the group for an elliptic curve. See the image for the question.

[image]

The inequality condition after simplification leads to $-2 \sqrt{p} \leq m \leq2 \sqrt{p}.$ Also, the order of the group will be a factor of $m$ (Lagrange theorem).

I found a research article on https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1134/S2070046611020075.pdf

I could still not figure out the exact answer.

Comment: Note that assignments may not be answered fully on this site, *hints* go either into the comment section or into an answer.

Comment: You might want to revisit how you got $-2\sqrt p \leq m \leq 2 \sqrt p$ from $(\sqrt p -1)^2 \leq m \leq (\sqrt p +1)^2$ since it's incorrect. Then, the right theorem will give you the answer.

Comment: @corpsfini Yes, I made a mistake. It's $-2 \sqrt{p} \leq m-(p+1) \leq2 \sqrt{p}$ and it's theorem of Hasse which will give me the answer. But what precisely is the answer?

Comment: Hasse is a bound, the exact answer is found via point counting. And this does look like homework.